# Could not log in; restarted MacBook Air; icons exchanged position; Got a login warning at my iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi, sleep-wake, menu-bar

I took my MacBook Air offline and put it to sleep. After some 4 hours, I opened the lid, entered the password wrongly, corrected it and hit enter. The password field and the "next" arrow were greyed out. This remained for some 10 seconds when I tried clicking on cancel button but nothing happened.Battery was at 35%.

Then I held the power button, it went to whatever state it goes into. I pressed the power button after a minute and logged in normally. A box appears asking if I want to open the applications that were open before the computer restarted because of a problem. I said No. Nothing more than Safari was open as far as I remember. I do have Ps, Acrobat, Lr, Tor VSCode, Spotify and a lot of RAW photos. I am at 15 GB free out of 128. Three windows of Finder opened when I reached the Desktop. Battery at 33%.

I noticed that the menu buttons of Wi-Fi and Bluetooth in menu bar exchanged their positions with all others at their original places.

Then I turned on Wi-Fi hotspot in an other android phone and connected both of them to it. I got a notification on my iPhone about my Apple ID being used somewhere but I didn't read it completely and pressed the only button shown "OK" by mistake.

Then to open Safari, I pressed cmd + space bar, typed "Sa" and it took time as it was indexing. I waited for the process to complete(for no reason).

Year and a half old MacBook Air running MacOS 10.14.2.

How to change the position of the aforementioned icons?

**Expected behaviour would be:**

1 Smooth login

2 Icons as they were

3 No notification on my iPhone as I have done the same sleep wake cycle so many times already.

4 No indexing time in spotlight as no major changes on disk were made.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing? Please mention expected and observed behavior.

Comment: @NimeshNeema done.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Now please don't point out that 4 different problems should be asked in four different questions. All of them happened in the same 20 minutes so are relevant. Can you withdraw your closing vote?

Comment: Right now there is a lot of information about potential problems, things which might have gone wrong, unkown messages/alerts etc., but no clearly formulated question besides about the fact that two icons in the menu bar changed places after reboot (which, to be honest, happens to me with more or less every reboot). So the best guess right now it, as indicated in the answer you already received, that the computer crashed, Spotlight index got corrupted and macOS automatically logged you into iMessage/Facetime again after restart.

Comment: As you already got an answer I'm a bit hesitating of recommending a rewrite of the question actually. It might be better to take the only clearly describable issue (icons changing positions) into a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes things unexpectedly happen and won't occur again. The alert on your iPhone was *probably* related to iMessage communicating with Apple's servers after the restart in an odd way and not something to worry about if it happened right at that time.

> A box appears asking if I want to open the applications that were open before the computer restarted because of a problem

This happens whenever an unexpected or forced shutdown occurs, and is to prevent the cause of the shutdown from reappearing if it's an application, etc.

You can reorder the icons in the menu bar by holding the command key and dragging them to the appropriate location.

Spotlight indexing also sometimes occurs after a restart. Unless it is completely losing your indexed state (which would take a long while to reindex!), then this is also expected behavior.

---

If you're worried about the computer, then restart it and see that it restarts smoothly. If it does, I would take no further action unless it happens again.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Could you shed some light on password field getting stuck if possible ?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii sounds like the computer froze up for some reason – unsure the cause